I installed really-simple-ssl on my wordpress site and now i get internal error 500
I installed really-simple-ssl on my wordpress site and now i get internal error 500. The plugin must have changed some settings. i was able to delete the plugin via terminal but the site is still down. can someone please help

What do your server logs say about the 500 error?

Invaled SSH Key entry - expired key

i didn't know how to create a ssl certificate with the google vm so i install the wordpress plugin really-simple-ssl and ran it. and it crashed my site.

Most likely, the plugin broke the webserver configuration. Which web server? Take a crash course on that webserver to understand what to look for.
